# Properties of Relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I don't understand this exercise from the book:

> There are $16$ possible different relations $R$ on the set $A=\{a,b\}$. Describe all of them.

Firstly, this is the definition of a relation:

> A relation on a set $A$ is a subset $R\subseteq A\times A$.

So in the exercise above, shoudln't $R$  be the subset of $A\times A=\{(a,a), (a,b), (b,a), (b,b)\}$?

Comment: There are many subsets of $A \times A$, and each of them is a relation. $\{(a,b), (b,a)\}$ is an example of another such subset.

Comment: Your second yellow parraph is where the solution to your question is: **any** subset of $\;A\times A\;$ is a relation, so how many subsets a set with four elements has?

Comment: Oh, I get it now, thanks!